# How to restore content of page from the cache in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cache

I want **restore the page** of the site I visited, but **without internet connection**. Is it possible in Chrome?

I can find a link and a title of the page in my history in Chrome (History button or *Ctrl+H*).

How can I get content of this page from cache? Or Chrome keeps only a page link with title without content?

I think content of the page should be kept also. But how can I get it?

I use last version  23.0.1271.97 of the Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

`chrome://cache/` lists the items that are cached. In Firefox, it's `about:cache`.

From there, you can search for `.html` sites.

[image]

Copy the URL to your omnibox, then open it.

Comment: I see now what you mean. I didn't know you had to paste the URL in the omnibox *again*. Which works – it shows the cached page without internet connection until you reload it. Maybe in the future you can be more specific? That way it's easier to understand what to do. Thanks!

Comment: firefox provide link to click but chrome doesn't provide it ...and yes sure for next time

Answer (score 1):

In case you have Chromium forwarding to "chrome://view-http-cache/..." that doesnt show deflated page data you can try following approach for restoring a single file - be aware that dependent files (images, included scripts / css) wont be restored automatically.

In "chrome://view-http-cache/...":

1. hit "F12"
2. go to "Console"
3. copy/paste code below and hit enter
4. for chrome use the Download link to download a inflated file

   ```
   var log = function(target, type, msg) {
       var elem = window.document.createElement('div');
       elem.innerHTML = new Date()+"<br /> - "+type+": "+msg+"<br />";
       target.appendChild(elem);
   }

   /* pako 1.0.5 nodeca/pako */
   !function(e){if("object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module)module.exports=e();else if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define([],e);else{var t;t="undefined"!=typeof window?window:"undefined"!=typeof global?global:"undefined"!=typeof self?self:this,t.pako=e()}}(function(){return function e(t,i,n){function a(o,s){if(!i[o]){if(!t[o]){var f="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!s&&f)return f(o,!0);if(r)return r(o,!0);var l=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw l.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",l}var d=i[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(d.exports,function(e){var i=t[o][1][e];return a(i?i:e)},d,d.exports,e,t,i,n)}return i[o].exports}for(var r="function"==typeof require&&require,o=0;o<n.length;o++)a(n[o]);return a}({1:[function(e,t,i){"use strict";var n="undefined"!=typeof Uint8Array&&"undefined"!=typeof Uint16Array&&"undefined"!=typeof Int32Array;i.assign=function(e){for(var t=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);t.length;){var i=t.shift();if(i){if("object"!=typeof i)throw new TypeError(i+"must be non-object");for(var n in i)i.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(e[n]=i[n])}}return e},i.shrinkBuf=function(e,t){return e.length===t?e:e.subarray?e.subarray(0,t):(e.length=t,e)};var a={arraySet:function(e,t,i,n,a){if(t.subarray&&e.subarray)return void e.set(t.subarray(i,i+n),a);for(var r=0;r<n;r++)e[a+r]=t[i+r]},flattenChunks:function(e){var t,i,n,a,r,o;for(n=0,t=0,i=e.length;t<i;t++)n+=e[t].length;for(o=new Uint8Array(n),a=0,t=0,i=e.length;t<i;t++)r=e[t],o.set(r,a),a+=r.length;return o}},r={arraySet:function(e,t,i,n,a){for(var r=0;r<n;r++)e[a+r]=t[i+r]},flattenChunks:function(e){return[].concat.apply([],e)}};i.setTyped=function(e){e?(i.Buf8=Uint8Array,i.Buf16=Uint16Array,i.Buf32=Int32Array,i.assign(i,a)):(i.Buf8=Array,i.Buf16=Array,i.Buf32=Array,i.assign(i,r))},i.setTyped(n)},{}],2:[function(e,t,i){"use strict";function n(e,t){if(t<65537&&(e.subarray&&o||!e.subarray&&r))return String.fromCharCode.apply(null,a.shrinkBuf(e,t));for(var i="",n=0;n<t;n++)i+=String.fromCharCode(e[n]);return i}var a=e("./common"),r=!0,o=!0;try{String.fromCharCode.apply(null,[0])}catch(e){r=!1}try{String.fromCharCode.apply(null,new Uint8Array(1))}catch(e){o=!1}for(var s=new a.Buf8(256),f=0;f<256;f++)s[f]=f>=252?6:f>=248?5:f>=240?4:f>=224?3:f>=192?2:1;s[254]=s[254]=1,i.string2buf=function(e){var t,i,n,r,o,s=e.length,f=0;for(r=0;r<s;r++)i=e.charCodeAt(r),55296===(64512&i)&&r+1<s&&(n=e.charCodeAt(r+1),56320===(64512&n)&&(i=65536+(i-55296<<10)+(n-56320),r++)),f+=i<128?1:i<2048?2:i<65536?3:4;for(t=new a.Buf8(f),o=0,r=0;o<f;r++)i=e.charCodeAt(r),55296===(64512&i)&&r+1<s&&(n=e.charCodeAt(r+1),56320===(64512&n)&&(i=65536+(i-55296<<10)+(n-56320),r++)),i<128?t[o++]=i:i<2048?(t[o++]=192|i>>>6,t[o++]=128|63&i):i<65536?(t[o++]=224|i>>>12,t[o++]=128|i>>>6&63,t[o++]=128|63&i):(t[o++]=240|i>>>18,t[o++]=128|i>>>12&63,t[o++]=128|i>>>6&63,t[o++]=128|63&i);return t},i.buf2binstring=function(e){return n(e,e.length)},i.binstring2buf=function(e){for(var t=new a.Buf8(e.length),i=0,n=t.length;i<n;i++)t[i]=e.charCodeAt(i);return t},i.buf2string=function(e,t){var i,a,r,o,f=t||e.length,l=new Array(2*f);for(a=0,i=0;i<f;)if(r=e[i++],r<128)l[a++]=r;else if(o=s[r],o>4)l[a++]=65533,i+=o-1;else{for(r&=2===o?31:3===o?15:7;o>1&&i<f;)r=r<<6|63&e[i++],o--;o>1?l[a++]=65533:r<65536?l[a++]=r:(r-=65536,l[a++]=55296|r>>10&1023,l[a++]=56320|1023&r)}return n(l,a)},i.utf8border=function(e,t){var i;for(t=t||e.length,t>e.length&&(t=e.length),i=t-1;i>=0&&128===(192&e[i]);)i--;return i<0?t:0===i?t:i+s[e[i]]>t?i:t}},{"./common":1}],3:[function(e,t,i){"use strict";function n(e,t,i,n){for(var a=65535&e|0,r=e>>>16&65535|0,o=0;0!==i;){o=i>2e3?2e3:i,i-=o;do a=a+t[n++]|0,r=r+a|0;while(--o);a%=65521,r%=65521}return a|r<<16|0}t.exports=n},{}],4:[function(e,t,i){"use strict";t.exports={Z_NO_FLUSH:0,Z_PARTIAL_FLUSH:1,Z_SYNC_FLUSH:2,Z_FULL_FLUSH:3,Z_FINISH:4,Z_BLOCK:5,Z_TREES:6,Z_OK:0,Z_STREAM_END:1,Z_NEED_DICT:2,Z_ERRNO:-1,Z_STREAM_ERROR:-2,Z_DATA_ERROR:-3,Z_BUF_ERROR:-5,Z_NO_COMPRESSION:0,Z_BEST_SPEED:1,Z_BEST_COMPRESSION:9,Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION:-1,Z_FILTERED:1,Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY:2,Z_RLE:3,Z_FIXED:4,Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY:0,Z_BINARY:0,Z_TEXT:1,Z_UNKNOWN:2,Z_DEFLATED:8}},{}],5:[function(e,t,i){"use strict";function n(){for(var e,t=[],i=0;i<256;i++){e=i;for(var n=0;n<8;n++)e=1&e?3988292384^e>>>1:e>>>1;t[i]=e}return t}function a(e,t,i,n){var a=r,o=n+i;e^=-1;for(var s=n;s<o;s++)e=e>>>8^a[255&(e^t[s])];return e^-1}var r=n();t.exports=a},{}],6:[function(e,t,i){"use strict";function n(){this.text=0,this.time=0,this.xflags=0,this.os=0,this.extra=null,this.extra_len=0,this.name="",this.comment="",this.hcrc=0,this.done=!1}t.exports=n},{}],7:[function(e,t,i){"use strict";var n=30,a=12;t.exports=function(e,t){var i,r,o,s,f,l,d,u,c,h,b,w,m,k,_,g,v,p,x,y,S,E,B,Z,A;i=e.state,r=e.next_in,Z=e.input,o=r+(e.avail_in-5),s=e.next_out,A=e.output,f=s-(t-e.avail_out),l=s+(e.avail_out-257),d=i.dmax,u=i.wsize,c=i.whave,h=i.wnext,b=i.window,w=i.hold,m=i.bits,k=i.lencode,_=i.distcode,g=(1<<i.lenbits)-1,v=(1<<i.distbits)-1;e:do{m<15&&(w+=Z[r++]<<m,m+=8,w+=Z[r++]<<m,m+=8),p=k[w&g];t:for(;;){if(x=p>>>24,w>>>=x,m-=x,x=p>>>16&255,0===x)A[s++]=65535&p;else{if(!(16&x)){if(0===(64&x)){p=k[(65535&p)+(w&(1<<x)-1)];continue t}if(32&x){i.mode=a;break e}e.msg="invalid literal/length code",i.mode=n;break e}y=65535&p,x&=15,x&&(m<x&&(w+=Z[r++]<<m,m+=8),y+=w&(1<<x)-1,w>>>=x,m-=x),m<15&&(w+=Z[r++]<<m,m+=8,w+=Z[r++]<<m,m+=8),p=_[w&v];i:for(;;){if(x=p>>>24,w>>>=x,m-=x,x=p>>>16&255,!(16&x)){if(0===(64&x)){p=_[(65535&p)+(w&(1<<x)-1)];continue i}e.msg="invalid distance code",i.mode=n;break e}if(S=65535&p,x&=15,m<x&&(w+=Z[r++]<<m,m+=8,m<x&&(w+=Z[r++]<<m,m+=8)),S+=w&(1<<x)-1,S>d){e.msg="invalid distance too far back",i.mode=n;break e}if(w>>>=x,m-=x,x=s-f,S>x){if(x=S-x,x>c&&i.sane){e.msg="invalid distance too far back",i.mode=n;break e}if(E=0,B=b,0===h){if(E+=u-x,x<y){y-=x;do A[s++]=b[E++];while(--x);E=s-S,B=A}}else if(h<x){if(E+=u+h-x,x-=h,x<y){y-=x;do A[s++]=b[E++];while(--x);if(E=0,h<y){x=h,y-=x;do A[s++]=b[E++];while(--x);E=s-S,B=A}}}else if(E+=h-x,x<y){y-=x;do A[s++]=b[E++];while(--x);E=s-S,B=A}for(;y>2;)A[s++]=B[E++],A[s++]=B[E++],A[s++]=B[E++],y-=3;y&&(A[s++]=B[E++],y>1&&(A[s++]=B[E++]))}else{E=s-S;do A[s++]=A[E++],A[s++]=A[E++],A[s++]=A[E++],y-=3;while(y>2);y&&(A[s++]=A[E++],y>1&&(A[s++]=A[E++]))}break}}break}}while(r<o&&s<l);y=m>>3,r-=y,m-=y<<3,w&=(1<<m)-1,e.next_in=r,e.next_out=s,e.avail_in=r<o?5+(o-r):5-(r-o),e.avail_out=s<l?257+(l-s):257-(s-l),i.hold=w,i.bits=m}},{}],8:[function(e,t,i){"use strict";function n(e){return(e>>>24&255)+(e>>>8&65280)+((65280&e)<<8)+((255&e)<<24)}function a(){this.mode=0,this.last=!1,this.wrap=0,this.havedict=!1,this.flags=0,this.dmax=0,this.check=0,this.total=0,this.head=null,this.wbits=0,this.wsize=0,this.whave=0,this.wnext=0,this.window=null,this.hold=0,this.bits=0,this.length=0,this.offset=0,this.extra=0,this.lencode=null,this.distcode=null,this.lenbits=0,this.distbits=0,this.ncode=0,this.nlen=0,this.ndist=0,this.have=0,this.next=null,this.lens=new _.Buf16(320),this.work=new _.Buf16(288),this.lendyn=null,this.distdyn=null,this.sane=0,this.back=0,this.was=0}function r(e){var t;return e&&e.state?(t=e.state,e.total_in=e.total_out=t.total=0,e.msg="",t.wrap&&(e.adler=1&t.wrap),t.mode=D,t.last=0,t.havedict=0,t.dmax=32768,t.head=null,t.hold=0,t.bits=0,t.lencode=t.lendyn=new _.Buf32(we),t.distcode=t.distdyn=new _.Buf32(me),t.sane=1,t.back=-1,z):C}function o(e){var t;return e&&e.state?(t=e.state,t.wsize=0,t.whave=0,t.wnext=0,r(e)):C}function s(e,t){var i,n;return e&&e.state?(n=e.state,t<0?(i=0,t=-t):(i=(t>>4)+1,t<48&&(t&=15)),t&&(t<8||t>15)?C:(null!==n.window&&n.wbits!==t&&(n.window=null),n.wrap=i,n.wbits=t,o(e))):C}function f(e,t){var i,n;return e?(n=new a,e.state=n,n.window=null,i=s(e,t),i!==z&&(e.state=null),i):C}function l(e){return f(e,_e)}function d(e){if(ge){var t;for(m=new _.Buf32(512),k=new _.Buf32(32),t=0;t<144;)e.lens[t++]=8;for(;t<256;)e.lens[t++]=9;for(;t<280;)e.lens[t++]=7;for(;t<288;)e.lens[t++]=8;for(x(S,e.lens,0,288,m,0,e.work,{bits:9}),t=0;t<32;)e.lens[t++]=5;x(E,e.lens,0,32,k,0,e.work,{bits:5}),ge=!1}e.lencode=m,e.lenbits=9,e.distcode=k,e.distbits=5}function u(e,t,i,n){var a,r=e.state;return null===r.window&&(r.wsize=1<<r.wbits,r.wnext=0,r.whave=0,r.window=new _.Buf8(r.wsize)),n>=r.wsize?(_.arraySet(r.window,t,i-r.wsize,r.wsize,0),r.wnext=0,r.whave=r.wsize):(a=r.wsize-r.wnext,a>n&&(a=n),_.arraySet(r.window,t,i-n,a,r.wnext),n-=a,n?(_.arraySet(r.window,t,i-n,n,0),r.wnext=n,r.whave=r.wsize):(r.wnext+=a,r.wnext===r.wsize&&(r.wnext=0),r.whave<r.wsize&&(r.whave+=a))),0}function c(e,t){var i,a,r,o,s,f,l,c,h,b,w,m,k,we,me,ke,_e,ge,ve,pe,xe,ye,Se,Ee,Be=0,Ze=new _.Buf8(4),Ae=[16,17,18,0,8,7,9,6,10,5,11,4,12,3,13,2,14,1,15];if(!e||!e.state||!e.output||!e.input&&0!==e.avail_in)return C;i=e.state,i.mode===X&&(i.mode=W),s=e.next_out,r=e.output,l=e.avail_out,o=e.next_in,a=e.input,f=e.avail_in,c=i.hold,h=i.bits,b=f,w=l,ye=z;e:for(;;)switch(i.mode){case D:if(0===i.wrap){i.mode=W;break}for(;h<16;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}if(2&i.wrap&&35615===c){i.check=0,Ze[0]=255&c,Ze[1]=c>>>8&255,i.check=v(i.check,Ze,2,0),c=0,h=0,i.mode=F;break}if(i.flags=0,i.head&&(i.head.done=!1),!(1&i.wrap)||(((255&c)<<8)+(c>>8))%31){e.msg="incorrect header check",i.mode=ce;break}if((15&c)!==U){e.msg="unknown compression method",i.mode=ce;break}if(c>>>=4,h-=4,xe=(15&c)+8,0===i.wbits)i.wbits=xe;else if(xe>i.wbits){e.msg="invalid window size",i.mode=ce;break}i.dmax=1<<xe,e.adler=i.check=1,i.mode=512&c?q:X,c=0,h=0;break;case F:for(;h<16;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}if(i.flags=c,(255&i.flags)!==U){e.msg="unknown compression method",i.mode=ce;break}if(57344&i.flags){e.msg="unknown header flags set",i.mode=ce;break}i.head&&(i.head.text=c>>8&1),512&i.flags&&(Ze[0]=255&c,Ze[1]=c>>>8&255,i.check=v(i.check,Ze,2,0)),c=0,h=0,i.mode=L;case L:for(;h<32;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}i.head&&(i.head.time=c),512&i.flags&&(Ze[0]=255&c,Ze[1]=c>>>8&255,Ze[2]=c>>>16&255,Ze[3]=c>>>24&255,i.check=v(i.check,Ze,4,0)),c=0,h=0,i.mode=H;case H:for(;h<16;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}i.head&&(i.head.xflags=255&c,i.head.os=c>>8),512&i.flags&&(Ze[0]=255&c,Ze[1]=c>>>8&255,i.check=v(i.check,Ze,2,0)),c=0,h=0,i.mode=M;case M:if(1024&i.flags){for(;h<16;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}i.length=c,i.head&&(i.head.extra_len=c),512&i.flags&&(Ze[0]=255&c,Ze[1]=c>>>8&255,i.check=v(i.check,Ze,2,0)),c=0,h=0}else i.head&&(i.head.extra=null);i.mode=j;case j:if(1024&i.flags&&(m=i.length,m>f&&(m=f),m&&(i.head&&(xe=i.head.extra_len-i.length,i.head.extra||(i.head.extra=new Array(i.head.extra_len)),_.arraySet(i.head.extra,a,o,m,xe)),512&i.flags&&(i.check=v(i.check,a,m,o)),f-=m,o+=m,i.length-=m),i.length))break e;i.length=0,i.mode=K;case K:if(2048&i.flags){if(0===f)break e;m=0;do xe=a[o+m++],i.head&&xe&&i.length<65536&&(i.head.name+=String.fromCharCode(xe));while(xe&&m<f);if(512&i.flags&&(i.check=v(i.check,a,m,o)),f-=m,o+=m,xe)break e}else i.head&&(i.head.name=null);i.length=0,i.mode=P;case P:if(4096&i.flags){if(0===f)break e;m=0;do xe=a[o+m++],i.head&&xe&&i.length<65536&&(i.head.comment+=String.fromCharCode(xe));while(xe&&m<f);if(512&i.flags&&(i.check=v(i.check,a,m,o)),f-=m,o+=m,xe)break e}else i.head&&(i.head.comment=null);i.mode=Y;case Y:if(512&i.flags){for(;h<16;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}if(c!==(65535&i.check)){e.msg="header crc mismatch",i.mode=ce;break}c=0,h=0}i.head&&(i.head.hcrc=i.flags>>9&1,i.head.done=!0),e.adler=i.check=0,i.mode=X;break;case q:for(;h<32;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}e.adler=i.check=n(c),c=0,h=0,i.mode=G;case G:if(0===i.havedict)return e.next_out=s,e.avail_out=l,e.next_in=o,e.avail_in=f,i.hold=c,i.bits=h,N;e.adler=i.check=1,i.mode=X;case X:if(t===Z||t===A)break e;case W:if(i.last){c>>>=7&h,h-=7&h,i.mode=le;break}for(;h<3;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}switch(i.last=1&c,c>>>=1,h-=1,3&c){case 0:i.mode=J;break;case 1:if(d(i),i.mode=ie,t===A){c>>>=2,h-=2;break e}break;case 2:i.mode=$;break;case 3:e.msg="invalid block type",i.mode=ce}c>>>=2,h-=2;break;case J:for(c>>>=7&h,h-=7&h;h<32;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}if((65535&c)!==(c>>>16^65535)){e.msg="invalid stored block lengths",i.mode=ce;break}if(i.length=65535&c,c=0,h=0,i.mode=Q,t===A)break e;case Q:i.mode=V;case V:if(m=i.length){if(m>f&&(m=f),m>l&&(m=l),0===m)break e;_.arraySet(r,a,o,m,s),f-=m,o+=m,l-=m,s+=m,i.length-=m;break}i.mode=X;break;case $:for(;h<14;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}if(i.nlen=(31&c)+257,c>>>=5,h-=5,i.ndist=(31&c)+1,c>>>=5,h-=5,i.ncode=(15&c)+4,c>>>=4,h-=4,i.nlen>286||i.ndist>30){e.msg="too many length or distance symbols",i.mode=ce;break}i.have=0,i.mode=ee;case ee:for(;i.have<i.ncode;){for(;h<3;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}i.lens[Ae[i.have++]]=7&c,c>>>=3,h-=3}for(;i.have<19;)i.lens[Ae[i.have++]]=0;if(i.lencode=i.lendyn,i.lenbits=7,Se={bits:i.lenbits},ye=x(y,i.lens,0,19,i.lencode,0,i.work,Se),i.lenbits=Se.bits,ye){e.msg="invalid code lengths set",i.mode=ce;break}i.have=0,i.mode=te;case te:for(;i.have<i.nlen+i.ndist;){for(;Be=i.lencode[c&(1<<i.lenbits)-1],me=Be>>>24,ke=Be>>>16&255,_e=65535&Be,!(me<=h);){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}if(_e<16)c>>>=me,h-=me,i.lens[i.have++]=_e;else{if(16===_e){for(Ee=me+2;h<Ee;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}if(c>>>=me,h-=me,0===i.have){e.msg="invalid bit length repeat",i.mode=ce;break}xe=i.lens[i.have-1],m=3+(3&c),c>>>=2,h-=2}else if(17===_e){for(Ee=me+3;h<Ee;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}c>>>=me,h-=me,xe=0,m=3+(7&c),c>>>=3,h-=3}else{for(Ee=me+7;h<Ee;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}c>>>=me,h-=me,xe=0,m=11+(127&c),c>>>=7,h-=7}if(i.have+m>i.nlen+i.ndist){e.msg="invalid bit length repeat",i.mode=ce;break}for(;m--;)i.lens[i.have++]=xe}}if(i.mode===ce)break;if(0===i.lens[256]){e.msg="invalid code -- missing end-of-block",i.mode=ce;break}if(i.lenbits=9,Se={bits:i.lenbits},ye=x(S,i.lens,0,i.nlen,i.lencode,0,i.work,Se),i.lenbits=Se.bits,ye){e.msg="invalid literal/lengths set",i.mode=ce;break}if(i.distbits=6,i.distcode=i.distdyn,Se={bits:i.distbits},ye=x(E,i.lens,i.nlen,i.ndist,i.distcode,0,i.work,Se),i.distbits=Se.bits,ye){e.msg="invalid distances set",i.mode=ce;break}if(i.mode=ie,t===A)break e;case ie:i.mode=ne;case ne:if(f>=6&&l>=258){e.next_out=s,e.avail_out=l,e.next_in=o,e.avail_in=f,i.hold=c,i.bits=h,p(e,w),s=e.next_out,r=e.output,l=e.avail_out,o=e.next_in,a=e.input,f=e.avail_in,c=i.hold,h=i.bits,i.mode===X&&(i.back=-1);break}for(i.back=0;Be=i.lencode[c&(1<<i.lenbits)-1],me=Be>>>24,ke=Be>>>16&255,_e=65535&Be,!(me<=h);){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}if(ke&&0===(240&ke)){for(ge=me,ve=ke,pe=_e;Be=i.lencode[pe+((c&(1<<ge+ve)-1)>>ge)],me=Be>>>24,ke=Be>>>16&255,_e=65535&Be,!(ge+me<=h);){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}c>>>=ge,h-=ge,i.back+=ge}if(c>>>=me,h-=me,i.back+=me,i.length=_e,0===ke){i.mode=fe;break}if(32&ke){i.back=-1,i.mode=X;break}if(64&ke){e.msg="invalid literal/length code",i.mode=ce;break}i.extra=15&ke,i.mode=ae;case ae:if(i.extra){for(Ee=i.extra;h<Ee;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}i.length+=c&(1<<i.extra)-1,c>>>=i.extra,h-=i.extra,i.back+=i.extra}i.was=i.length,i.mode=re;case re:for(;Be=i.distcode[c&(1<<i.distbits)-1],me=Be>>>24,ke=Be>>>16&255,_e=65535&Be,!(me<=h);){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}if(0===(240&ke)){for(ge=me,ve=ke,pe=_e;Be=i.distcode[pe+((c&(1<<ge+ve)-1)>>ge)],me=Be>>>24,ke=Be>>>16&255,_e=65535&Be,!(ge+me<=h);){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}c>>>=ge,h-=ge,i.back+=ge}if(c>>>=me,h-=me,i.back+=me,64&ke){e.msg="invalid distance code",i.mode=ce;break}i.offset=_e,i.extra=15&ke,i.mode=oe;case oe:if(i.extra){for(Ee=i.extra;h<Ee;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}i.offset+=c&(1<<i.extra)-1,c>>>=i.extra,h-=i.extra,i.back+=i.extra}if(i.offset>i.dmax){e.msg="invalid distance too far back",i.mode=ce;break}i.mode=se;case se:if(0===l)break e;if(m=w-l,i.offset>m){if(m=i.offset-m,m>i.whave&&i.sane){e.msg="invalid distance too far back",i.mode=ce;break}m>i.wnext?(m-=i.wnext,k=i.wsize-m):k=i.wnext-m,m>i.length&&(m=i.length),we=i.window}else we=r,k=s-i.offset,m=i.length;m>l&&(m=l),l-=m,i.length-=m;do r[s++]=we[k++];while(--m);0===i.length&&(i.mode=ne);break;case fe:if(0===l)break e;r[s++]=i.length,l--,i.mode=ne;break;case le:if(i.wrap){for(;h<32;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c|=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}if(w-=l,e.total_out+=w,i.total+=w,w&&(e.adler=i.check=i.flags?v(i.check,r,w,s-w):g(i.check,r,w,s-w)),w=l,(i.flags?c:n(c))!==i.check){e.msg="incorrect data check",i.mode=ce;break}c=0,h=0}i.mode=de;case de:if(i.wrap&&i.flags){for(;h<32;){if(0===f)break e;f--,c+=a[o++]<<h,h+=8}if(c!==(4294967295&i.total)){e.msg="incorrect length check",i.mode=ce;break}c=0,h=0}i.mode=ue;case ue:ye=R;break e;case ce:ye=O;break e;case he:return I;case be:default:return C}return e.next_out=s,e.avail_out=l,e.next_in=o,e.avail_in=f,i.hold=c,i.bits=h,(i.wsize||w!==e.avail_out&&i.mode<ce&&(i.mode<le||t!==B))&&u(e,e.output,e.next_out,w-e.avail_out)?(i.mode=he,I):(b-=e.avail_in,w-=e.avail_out,e.total_in+=b,e.total_out+=w,i.total+=w,i.wrap&&w&&(e.adler=i.check=i.flags?v(i.check,r,w,e.next_out-w):g(i.check,r,w,e.next_out-w)),e.data_type=i.bits+(i.last?64:0)+(i.mode===X?128:0)+(i.mode===ie||i.mode===Q?256:0),(0===b&&0===w||t===B)&&ye===z&&(ye=T),ye)}function h(e){if(!e||!e.state)return C;var t=e.state;return t.window&&(t.window=null),e.state=null,z}function b(e,t){var i;return e&&e.state?(i=e.state,0===(2&i.wrap)?C:(i.head=t,t.done=!1,z)):C}function w(e,t){var i,n,a,r=t.length;return e&&e.state?(i=e.state,0!==i.wrap&&i.mode!==G?C:i.mode===G&&(n=1,n=g(n,t,r,0),n!==i.check)?O:(a=u(e,t,r,r))?(i.mode=he,I):(i.havedict=1,z)):C}var m,k,_=e("../utils/common"),g=e("./adler32"),v=e("./crc32"),p=e("./inffast"),x=e("./inftrees"),y=0,S=1,E=2,B=4,Z=5,A=6,z=0,R=1,N=2,C=-2,O=-3,I=-4,T=-5,U=8,D=1,F=2,L=3,H=4,M=5,j=6,K=7,P=8,Y=9,q=10,G=11,X=12,W=13,J=14,Q=15,V=16,$=17,ee=18,te=19,ie=20,ne=21,ae=22,re=23,oe=24,se=25,fe=26,le=27,de=28,ue=29,ce=30,he=31,be=32,we=852,me=592,ke=15,_e=ke,ge=!0;i.inflateReset=o,i.inflateReset2=s,i.inflateResetKeep=r,i.inflateInit=l,i.inflateInit2=f,i.inflate=c,i.inflateEnd=h,i.inflateGetHeader=b,i.inflateSetDictionary=w,i.inflateInfo="pako inflate (from Nodeca project)"},{"../utils/common":1,"./adler32":3,"./crc32":5,"./inffast":7,"./inftrees":9}],9:[function(e,t,i){"use strict";var n=e("../utils/common"),a=15,r=852,o=592,s=0,f=1,l=2,d=[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,15,17,19,23,27,31,35,43,51,59,67,83,99,115,131,163,195,227,258,0,0],u=[16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,16,72,78],c=[1,2,3,4,5,7,9,13,17,25,33,49,65,97,129,193,257,385,513,769,1025,1537,2049,3073,4097,6145,8193,12289,16385,24577,0,0],h=[16,16,16,16,17,17,18,18,19,19,20,20,21,21,22,22,23,23,24,24,25,25,26,26,27,27,28,28,29,29,64,64];t.exports=function(e,t,i,b,w,m,k,_){var g,v,p,x,y,S,E,B,Z,A=_.bits,z=0,R=0,N=0,C=0,O=0,I=0,T=0,U=0,D=0,F=0,L=null,H=0,M=new n.Buf16(a+1),j=new n.Buf16(a+1),K=null,P=0;for(z=0;z<=a;z++)M[z]=0;for(R=0;R<b;R++)M[t[i+R]]++;for(O=A,C=a;C>=1&&0===M[C];C--);if(O>C&&(O=C),0===C)return w[m++]=20971520,w[m++]=20971520,_.bits=1,0;for(N=1;N<C&&0===M[N];N++);for(O<N&&(O=N),U=1,z=1;z<=a;z++)if(U<<=1,U-=M[z],U<0)return-1;if(U>0&&(e===s||1!==C))return-1;for(j[1]=0,z=1;z<a;z++)j[z+1]=j[z]+M[z];for(R=0;R<b;R++)0!==t[i+R]&&(k[j[t[i+R]]++]=R);if(e===s?(L=K=k,S=19):e===f?(L=d,H-=257,K=u,P-=257,S=256):(L=c,K=h,S=-1),F=0,R=0,z=N,y=m,I=O,T=0,p=-1,D=1<<O,x=D-1,e===f&&D>r||e===l&&D>o)return 1;for(;;){E=z-T,k[R]<S?(B=0,Z=k[R]):k[R]>S?(B=K[P+k[R]],Z=L[H+k[R]]):(B=96,Z=0),g=1<<z-T,v=1<<I,N=v;do v-=g,w[y+(F>>T)+v]=E<<24|B<<16|Z|0;while(0!==v);for(g=1<<z-1;F&g;)g>>=1;if(0!==g?(F&=g-1,F+=g):F=0,R++,0===--M[z]){if(z===C)break;z=t[i+k[R]]}if(z>O&&(F&x)!==p){for(0===T&&(T=O),y+=N,I=z-T,U=1<<I;I+T<C&&(U-=M[I+T],!(U<=0));)I++,U<<=1;if(D+=1<<I,e===f&&D>r||e===l&&D>o)return 1;p=F&x,w[p]=O<<24|I<<16|y-m|0}}return 0!==F&&(w[y+F]=z-T<<24|64<<16|0),_.bits=O,0}},{"../utils/common":1}],10:[function(e,t,i){"use strict";t.exports={2:"need dictionary",1:"stream end",0:"","-1":"file error","-2":"stream error","-3":"data error","-4":"insufficient memory","-5":"buffer error","-6":"incompatible version"}},{}],11:[function(e,t,i){"use strict";function n(){this.input=null,this.next_in=0,this.avail_in=0,this.total_in=0,this.output=null,this.next_out=0,this.avail_out=0,this.total_out=0,this.msg="",this.state=null,this.data_type=2,this.adler=0}t.exports=n},{}],"/lib/inflate.js":[function(e,t,i){"use strict";function n(e){if(!(this instanceof n))return new n(e);this.options=s.assign({chunkSize:16384,windowBits:0,to:""},e||{});var t=this.options;t.raw&&t.windowBits>=0&&t.windowBits<16&&(t.windowBits=-t.windowBits,0===t.windowBits&&(t.windowBits=-15)),!(t.windowBits>=0&&t.windowBits<16)||e&&e.windowBits||(t.windowBits+=32),t.windowBits>15&&t.windowBits<48&&0===(15&t.windowBits)&&(t.windowBits|=15),this.err=0,this.msg="",this.ended=!1,this.chunks=[],this.strm=new u,this.strm.avail_out=0;var i=o.inflateInit2(this.strm,t.windowBits);if(i!==l.Z_OK)throw new Error(d[i]);this.header=new c,o.inflateGetHeader(this.strm,this.header)}function a(e,t){var i=new n(t);if(i.push(e,!0),i.err)throw i.msg||d[i.err];return i.result}function r(e,t){return t=t||{},t.raw=!0,a(e,t)}var o=e("./zlib/inflate"),s=e("./utils/common"),f=e("./utils/strings"),l=e("./zlib/constants"),d=e("./zlib/messages"),u=e("./zlib/zstream"),c=e("./zlib/gzheader"),h=Object.prototype.toString;n.prototype.push=function(e,t){var i,n,a,r,d,u,c=this.strm,b=this.options.chunkSize,w=this.options.dictionary,m=!1;if(this.ended)return!1;n=t===~~t?t:t===!0?l.Z_FINISH:l.Z_NO_FLUSH,"string"==typeof e?c.input=f.binstring2buf(e):"[object ArrayBuffer]"===h.call(e)?c.input=new Uint8Array(e):c.input=e,c.next_in=0,c.avail_in=c.input.length;do{if(0===c.avail_out&&(c.output=new s.Buf8(b),c.next_out=0,c.avail_out=b),i=o.inflate(c,l.Z_NO_FLUSH),i===l.Z_NEED_DICT&&w&&(u="string"==typeof w?f.string2buf(w):"[object ArrayBuffer]"===h.call(w)?new Uint8Array(w):w,i=o.inflateSetDictionary(this.strm,u)),i===l.Z_BUF_ERROR&&m===!0&&(i=l.Z_OK,m=!1),i!==l.Z_STREAM_END&&i!==l.Z_OK)return this.onEnd(i),this.ended=!0,!1;c.next_out&&(0!==c.avail_out&&i!==l.Z_STREAM_END&&(0!==c.avail_in||n!==l.Z_FINISH&&n!==l.Z_SYNC_FLUSH)||("string"===this.options.to?(a=f.utf8border(c.output,c.next_out),r=c.next_out-a,d=f.buf2string(c.output,a),c.next_out=r,c.avail_out=b-r,r&&s.arraySet(c.output,c.output,a,r,0),this.onData(d)):this.onData(s.shrinkBuf(c.output,c.next_out)))),0===c.avail_in&&0===c.avail_out&&(m=!0)}while((c.avail_in>0||0===c.avail_out)&&i!==l.Z_STREAM_END);return i===l.Z_STREAM_END&&(n=l.Z_FINISH),n===l.Z_FINISH?(i=o.inflateEnd(this.strm),this.onEnd(i),this.ended=!0,i===l.Z_OK):n!==l.Z_SYNC_FLUSH||(this.onEnd(l.Z_OK),c.avail_out=0,!0)},n.prototype.onData=function(e){this.chunks.push(e)},n.prototype.onEnd=function(e){e===l.Z_OK&&("string"===this.options.to?this.result=this.chunks.join(""):this.result=s.flattenChunks(this.chunks)),this.chunks=[],this.err=e,this.msg=this.strm.msg},i.Inflate=n,i.inflate=a,i.inflateRaw=r,i.ungzip=a},{"./utils/common":1,"./utils/strings":2,"./zlib/constants":4,"./zlib/gzheader":6,"./zlib/inflate":8,"./zlib/messages":10,"./zlib/zstream":11}]},{},[])("/lib/inflate.js")});

   var DR_outputDisplay = document.getElementById("DR_outputDisplay");
   if(DR_outputDisplay == undefined) {
     DR_outputDisplay = window.document.createElement('div');
     DR_outputDisplay.setAttribute("id", "DR_outputDisplay");
     DR_outputDisplay.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; top:15px; left: 15px; width: 480px; height: 200px; overflow: auto; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); border: 1px solid #000000; padding: 15px; font-size: 13px;");
     window.document.body.appendChild(DR_outputDisplay);
   }

   var p = window.document.createElement('div');
   p.innerHTML = new Date()+"<br /> - INFO Looking for deflated data in &lt;pre&gt;-Tag...<br />";
   DR_outputDisplay.appendChild(p);

   // assuming potential HEX-Table is shown in pre-tag.
   var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
   var hexElement = -1;
   // look for pre Tag that contains something like a HEX-Table with '1f 8b' and 14 more hex vals values in a row 
   for(var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
     if(elements[index].innerHTML.search(/ 1f +8b +[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] +[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] +[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] +[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] +[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] +[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] +[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] +[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] +[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] +[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] +[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] +[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] +[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] +[0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] /i) >= 0) {
       hexElement = index;

       log(DR_outputDisplay, "INFO", "Found deflated data: "+elements[index].innerHTML.substring(1, 40)+"...");
   //    console.log(elements[index].innerHTML);

       break;
     }
   }
   if(hexElement >= 0) {
     // split for easier data processing
     var hexRows = elements[hexElement].innerHTML.split('\n');

     // analyze first line to get an idea of how the HEX-Table is layoutted
     // - offset for data before actual HEX Values start
     // - delimiter for empty spaces used in between HEX values
     // - values per line is currently assumed to be 16
     var hexRowsOffset = hexRows[0].search(/ [0-9|a-f][0-9|a-f] /i);
     var hexDelimiter = -1; 
     while(hexRows[0][hexRowsOffset+3+(++hexDelimiter)] === ' ');
     var hexValuesPerLine = 16;

     log(DR_outputDisplay, "INFO", "Calculated: Offset for HEX of "+hexRowsOffset+", Delimiter Length of HEX of "+hexDelimiter+", Length of HEX per Line of "+hexValuesPerLine);

     // process in two steps. first push binary information in this hexValues Array. second shift everything in   ByteArray
     var hexValues = [];
     var hexRowOffset = 0;
     var stop = false;

     // first step: Run through all hexRows but stopping in case spaces are found in case of HEX-Values
     for(var index = 0; index < hexRows.length; index++) {
       hexRowOffset = hexRowsOffset+1;

       for(var iindex = 0; iindex < hexValuesPerLine; iindex++) {
         if(hexRows[index][hexRowOffset] === " ") { stop=true; break; }

         var val = hexRows[index].charCodeAt(hexRowOffset++);
         var val2 = hexRows[index].charCodeAt(hexRowOffset++);
         hexValues.push((val-48>9?val-96+9:val-48)*16+(val2-48>9?val2-96+9:val2-48));
         hexRowOffset += hexDelimiter;
       }
       if(stop) { break; }
     }

     // second step: Create a perfectly fitting ArrayBuffer as base for typed array Uint8Array and run through   hexValues shifting everything inside ArrayBuffer
     var ab = new ArrayBuffer(hexValues.length);
     var storage = new Uint8Array(ab);
     var value = 0;
     hexRowOffset=0;
     while((value = hexValues.shift())>=0) {
       storage[hexRowOffset++] = value;
     }

     var p = window.document.createElement('div');
     var blob = new Blob([String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(pako.inflate(storage)))], {type: "text/plain"});
     var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     log(DR_outputDisplay, "SUCCESS", "<a href="+url+" download='"+new Date()+".bin'>Download</a><br /><span style='font-size:14px; color: red;'>If link doesnt work, use link in textbox and open in new tab: </span><input type='text' value='"+url+"' style='width: 470px'/><br />");
   } else {
     log(DR_outputDisplay, "ERROR", "Could not find deflated data.<br />");
   }
   ```